# Page numbering countdown with roman

Tags: page-numbering

I want the page number to be descending and roman. When I change the page number to roman, it doesn't work correctly (uncomment line 9 in MWE and see the output).

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\textheight1cm
\begin{document}
    1 \newpage 2 \newpage 3
    \newpage
    \setcounter{page}{1}
    \let\oldthepage\thepage
    \renewcommand{\thepage}{\number\numexpr 4-\oldthepage\relax}
%   \renewcommand{\thepage}{\roman{page}}
    iii \newpage ii \newpage i
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the numeric value `\value{page}` in computations:

```
\documentclass{article}
\textheight1cm
\begin{document}
    1 \newpage 2 \newpage 3
    \newpage
    \setcounter{page}{1}

    \renewcommand{\thepage}{\romannumeral\numexpr 4-\value{page}\relax}
   
    iii \newpage ii \newpage i
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set the page number display to this to achieve a general, decreasing page number (in roman):

```
\renewcommand{\thepage}{%
  \romannumeral\numexpr
    \ifcsname @abspage@last\endcsname
      \csname @abspage@last\endcsname% Use \@abspage@last if it exists
    \else
      0% Otherwise use 0
    \fi
    -\value{page}+1%
  \relax}
```

It uses `\@abspage@last` (part of the LaTeX kernel since Oct 2020<sup>*</sup>) to capture the `abs`olute number of `page`s. Since this value relies on the `.aux`, you'll have to compile at least twice with any change in the total number of pages.

<sub><sup>*</sup> You may have to add `\usepackage{xparse}` to your preamble if you don't have an up-to-date LaTeX.</sub>